# Core Bluetooth - Issue in printing image on thermal printer (ESC/POS) from iOS (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, thermal-printer, ios-bluetooth

When I print images to a thermal printer over bluetooth (yes, after connecting to the printer as peripheral), the printing is slow and it prints blank lines all over the image.

When I print same data packet to a wifi socket (to other printer, which supports wifi connectivity), it prints images perfectly.

I am totally clueless on what could be the potential reason. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the output:[image]

Comment: This looks more like a problem (or rather lack of printing precision) with the printer itself, and not a software problem. Comparing your printout with one from another printer is also rather pointless, comparing with printouts from other apps (or the printer's test page) are more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for providing your insight. But actual scenario is different than you understood from the question. In actual, same printer prints correct image when printing from Android app, developed for the same printer. That means printer is not faulty. Also I had mentioned about wifi printer (note that wifi printer is of same manufacturer) just to clarify that the packet I am generating is also fine, as it is printing correctly on a wifi printer.

Comment: Hi Dipak,
Did you find a solution to this? I'm having similar problems with speed and sizing using obj c.

Comment: @Dipak Mishra Hi can you help me with image printing from Bluetooth thermal printer from iOS is have tried a lot but no success... please if you can help..